# Infinite series of measurable functions is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(S,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $f_1, f_2, \dots : S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions and let: $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{A}$ be disjoint.

Now consider:
$$f = \lim_{N\to\infty} S_N = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb{1}_{A_n}f_n$$.

It is clear that if this limit converges, then we would have that $f$ is measurable. However, I don't see why the limit would have to be convergent. I suppose that, given $N>M$ and due to $A_1, A_2,\dots$ being disjoint, we would only need that:

$$|S_N-S_M| \leq \sum_{n=M+1}^{N}|f_n| \rightarrow 0\quad \text{as}\quad N\rightarrow\infty$$

But I don't see why this has to be the case. Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: While it is written as an infinite sum, for any point $p\in S$ only finitely many of the summands in the definition of $f(p)$ are nonzero (in fact at most one)

Comment: The definition of $f$ is not valid since the limit need not exist.